# Number theory high school math competition question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$\gcd(2^{71} - 2, 3^{71} - 3, ..., 100^{71} - 100)$
I got $2 \cdot 3  \cdot  11  \cdot  71$ so far.
I think that might be the answer, but not sure how I can be sure.

Comment: What are you allowed to use?  The Euclidean algorithm suffices to show that $\gcd(2^{71}-2,3^{71}-3)=2\times 3\times 11\times 71$ which, together with what you've already shown, solves the problem.  But It's a bit hard to do with pencil and paper.

Comment: This is a math competition problem, so max they can use is a simple calculator.

Comment: I assume it would be quite hard to use Euclidean algorithm with just a simple calculator?

Comment: Well...I don't know.  $3^{71}\approx 7.5\times 10^{33}$ and that's large for a simple calculator to hold.  But the operation involved is very simple, virtually instantaneous in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gcd(2%5E71-2,3%5E71-3))  Perhaps there's a clever way to handle the calculation, though nothing leaps to mind.

Comment: You can eliminate most small primes quickly...since  there is always a primitive root $\pmod p$ you'd get $p-1\,|\,71$.  But for large $p$ I don't see how to show that it's impossible that $1,\cdots, 100$ each just happen to have very low order $\pmod p$. Though I guess you just need to look at $2^d$ where $d$ is a divisor of $70$.  Maybe that gives a cheap solution.

Comment: Correction:  in my prior comment I wrote $p-1\,|\,71$ where I had intended to write $p-1\,|\,70$.

Comment: Thx a lot for the info. I am tutoring a 7th grader for math competition, so I will tell him it’s ok to stop after finding 2, 3, 11 and 71

Comment: $7^{th}$ grade?  Then I'm impressed your student found $2,3,11,71$.  To be sure: I might well be missing a trick or two here.  The fact is that it is quite easy to resolve the matter with a little calculation...you just need to be able to manipulate fairly large numbers.

Comment: Highly unlikely he can solve this. I think this problem is tough even for strong high school students, but can’t hurt to teach him early. Thanks for info

Comment: This is an old Romanian Team Selection Test problem, from 2008. Indeed, it is a tough one.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, 
$$
\prod_{p-1\mid 70}p.
$$
I will prove it in a series of steps.

1. First, check that, if $p-1\mid 70$, then if $a\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, we clearly have the divisibility. If $a\not\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, then it follows that $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}\implies a^{70}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, hence, $a^{71}\equiv a\pmod{p}$. Hence, for every $p$ with $p-1\mid 70$, it holds that, $p\mid a^{71}-a$. Conversely, for any such prime divisor $p\mid {\rm gcd}(2^{71}-2,\dots,100^{71}-100)$ and $p<70$, it must hold that $p-1\mid 70$. To see this, let $g$ be a primitive root modulo $p$. Then, $g^{70}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, and thus, $p-1\mid 70$.
2. Next, we show if $p-1\mid 70$, then $p^2\nmid {\rm gcd}(2^{71}-2,\dots,100^{71}-100)$. To see this, simply take $a=p$, and observe that $p^{71}-p\not\equiv 0\pmod{p^2}$.
3. Finally, take a prime $p>71$. Let $P(x)=x^{70}-1$. From the given condition, it holds that, this polynomial admits $1,2,3,\dots,70,71$ as its roots modulo $p$, which contradicts with Lagrange's theorem. Hence, no prime $p>71$ can possibly divide the gcd.

The end.

Comment: Thx a lot for the answers. My student is only in 7th grade, so I will refrain trying to explain all of the above, but definitely useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.  $k^{71} - k = k(k^{70} - 1)$

by fermat's little theorem:

If $p-1|70$ and $p\not \mid k$ then $k^{70}\equiv 1 \pmod p$ and so $p|k^{70} -1$ and $p|k^{71} -k$.  And if $p\mid k$ then $p|k^{71}-k$.

So $2,3,11, 71$ all divide all $k^{71} - k$ so $2\cdot 3\cdot 11 \cdot 71|\gcd$.

For any other prime $p$ then for any $p\not \mid k$ then then $k^{70\pmod {p-1} \not \equiv 0}\not \equiv 1 \pmod p$ so $p\not \mid k^{71} -k$ for any $k$ that isn't a multiple of $p$.  So as non-multiples of $p$ exist, $p$ can not be a factor of the $\gcd$.

So $\gcd = 2^a3^b11^c71^d$. But as $p\not \mid p^{70} -1$ then $p^2\not \mid p^{71} - p$ so no higher powers factor into the $\gcd$.

So $\gcd = 2\cdot 3\cdot 11 \cdot 71$